# Show difference between mySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I want to display difference between tables by returning the names in table 1 that are not in Table 2.

Table 1:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | campaign_id | nickname |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 1  | 55          | name1    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 2  | 55          | name2    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 3  | 55          | name3    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 4  | 40          | name4    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 5  | 40          | name1    |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | book_id | name     |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | 55      | name1    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 2  | 55      | name2    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 55 | name3 |
+----+-------+
| 40 | name4 |
+----+-------+
| 40 | name1 |
+----+-------+
```

---

Sorry, my 2nd table has `name` instead of `nickname` so how I can use `USING` property?

Comment: You can edit your question or leave a comment on the provided if clarification is needed.

Comment: *how I can use USING property?* It's impossible if field's names differs.

Answer (score 1):

Left join where there is no match on the left (`IS NULL`):

```
SELECT campaign_id as id, tbl1.nickname as name
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON nickname=name
WHERE tbl2.id IS NULL
```

Alternately there is a MariaDB-10.3 syntax:

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~stretch-log |
> ```

> ```
> create table tbl1 (name varchar(20))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl1 values ('n1'),('n2'),('n6')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table tbl2 (name varchar(20))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl2 values ('n1'),('n2'),('n12')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select name from tbl1 except select name from tbl2
> ```
>
> ```
> | name |
> | :--- |
> | n6   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=68b682a4752a39cc49db7ce8f69949e0)*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT campaign_id id, nickname name
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE table1.campaign_id = table2.book_id
                     AND table1.nickname = table2.name )
```

or

```
SELECT table1.campaign_id id, table1.nickname name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table1.campaign_id = table2.book_id
      AND table1.nickname = table2.name
WHERE table2.name IS NULL
```